Edge IDs different between Blender's UI and headless mode
I’m working on a semi-automatic script to clean a mesh. Since no existing function can accurately identify which edges to dissolve, I’ve manually selected the appropriate edges and exported their IDs to a JSON file.
When I run my script in Blender's UI, it successfully dissolves the edges based on the IDs from the JSON file. However, when I try to execute the same script in headless mode (from a terminal, without the Blender UI), and then export the cleaned mesh to an OBJ file, the result is incorrect—the wrong edges are dissolved.
I have the same issue when dealing with vertices and faces.
Here is the function that should clean the mesh by dissolving specific edges:
def dissolve_mesh_edges(mesh: bpy.types.Object, edges: List[int]):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='EDGE')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    for edge_id in edges:
        if edge_id < len(mesh.data.edges):
            mesh.data.edges[edge_id].select = True
        else:
            raise IndexError(f"Edge ID {edge_id} is out of range.")

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.dissolve_edges()

How can I ensure the script behaves consistently in both the UI and headless modes?

You could add named attributes to the edges you want. With vertices it would be as easy as using weight painting.

@DanielMöller The thing is that I want to be able to select the edges on the original mesh. I shouldn't modify it by adding attributes to the edges I need to dissolve.

I think your problem is the way you're testing to see if the edges should be selected or not. I don't think the if edge_id < len(mesh.edges) is right. The way I'd do it is like this (not tested so there may be typos or something, just to illustrate the general method) or maybe you could mess with mesh.edges.foreach_set() method, if you were super concerned with performance but the naive way is fine in most cases I think.

@Jakemoyo My mesh has nearly a hundred thousand vertices, so I thought that checking all the vertices of the mesh would be inefficient. That's why I'm checking only the IDs of vertices I need to select and I use the condition if edge_id < len(mesh.data.edges) to make sure those IDs are not out of range. I haven't used mesh.edges.foreach_set(), so I'll have a look at this method. Thanks!

I took all the suggestions into consideration and concluded that relying on edge IDs (and by extension, face IDs) is not a reliable approach, as these IDs are inconsistent between the UI and headless modes. However, vertex IDs seem to remain consistent across both modes as long as no geometry modifications (like adding or deleting vertices) are performed.
Initially, I used a list of edge IDs imported from a JSON file. However, since my mesh contains about a hundred thousand vertices, checking all edges naively to determine which ones to select was inefficient. To optimize this process, I converted my list of edge IDs into a set of tuples containing vertex IDs.
Because sets and tuples are not natively supported by JSON, I switched to using Pickle for serialization. Here's the updated script:
import bpy
import pickle
from typing import Set, Tuple

def dissolve_mesh_edges(mesh: bpy.types.Object, edges: Set[Tuple[int, int]]):
    # Make sure no edges are selected
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='EDGE')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    # Select edges based on vertex pairs
    for edge in mesh.data.edges:
        v1, v2 = sorted(edge.vertices)
        if (v1, v2) in edges:
            edge.select = True

    # Dissolve the selected edges
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.dissolve_edges()

Explanation:

Serialization with Pickle:

Since JSON doesn't support sets or tuples, I used Pickle for data storage. This enables efficient lookups for edge selection.
Example of saving edges:
edges = {(10, 20), (30, 40), (50, 60)}
with open("edges.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(edges, f)


Example of loading edges:
with open("edges.pickle", "rb") as f:
    edges = pickle.load(f)




Efficient Edge Selection:

The sorted function ensures that the vertex pairs are ordered consistently. This eliminates the need to check both (v1, v2) and (v2, v1) in the set. This works because I made sure my data file has sorted vertex pairs already.
This convention is especially valuable for faces, where sorting the vertices reduces combinations significantly:

Triangles: 6 combinations → 1.
Quads: 24 combinations → 1.





Performance Note:
For very large meshes like mine, this approach is more efficient than iterating through all vertex combinations or relying on edge IDs. Using a set lookup for edge selection is highly performant, even with a large number of edges.
Limitations:

This method assumes the vertex IDs in the Pickle file are consistent with the current mesh geometry.
Any changes to the mesh (like adding or deleting vertices) will invalidate the saved data.

